# Devise after_sign_in_path_for generates routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to redirect users that login to their profile page but get the following error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"trooper_profiles"}
```

Here's the guide I'm following. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

In my application_controller I've added

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  trooper_trooper_profile_path
end
```

Rake routes shows:

```
trooper_trooper_profile POST   /troopers/:trooper_id/trooper_profile(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"trooper_profiles"}
new_trooper_trooper_profile GET    /troopers/:trooper_id/trooper_profile/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"trooper_profiles"}
edit_trooper_trooper_profile GET    /troopers/:trooper_id/trooper_profile/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"trooper_profiles"}
GET    /troopers/:trooper_id/trooper_profile(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"trooper_profiles"}
PUT    /troopers/:trooper_id/trooper_profile(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"trooper_profiles"}
DELETE /troopers/:trooper_id/trooper_profile(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"trooper_profiles"}
```

Server log

```
Started POST "/troopers/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-24 21:11:09 +1000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LhT6b4xu5bIJ5kwhS74L7dpaGbuR5BTdirh9AziD+Ew=", "trooper"=>{"email"=>"robert@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Trooper Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "troopers".* FROM "troopers" WHERE ("troopers"."email" = 'robert@example.com') LIMIT 1
AREL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "troopers" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2011-05-24 11:09:04.931050', "current_sign_in_at" = '2011-05-24 11:11:09.603249', "sign_in_count" = 44, "updated_at" = '2011-05-24 11:11:09.603773' WHERE ("troopers"."id" = 1)
Completed   in 149ms
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"trooper_profiles"}):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `after_sign_in_path_for'
```

Any idea on why the route doesn't match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not telling your path helper *which* trooper profile to display.

Try changing your `after_sign_in_path_for` method thus:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  trooper_trooper_profile_path(resource) # Note presence of 'resource'
end
```

Comment: Not sure if this is just me, but I had to put this in application_helper.rb, not in application_controller.rb. The documentation suggests putting in the controller, but after_sign_in_path_for is actually a helper, not a controller method.

Answer (score 0):

you are redirecting to post action